# Is it safe to wait on async task in .NET Core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, async-await

I have a situation when I have to override library synchronous method and make calls of my async methods in it (library  doesn't support async version). So I am gonna wait on task completion:

```
public override object LibMethod(){
   ...
   var res = myService.GetFromDbAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
   ...
}
```

I know that in ASP.NET Core there is no synchronizationcontext so it must be no worries about deadlocks. Does it mean that I can safely wait on async task like in my code ?

Comment: "I know that in .NET Core there is no synchronizationcontext" where do you know that from? Possibly you meant ASP.Net Core, see https://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html#you-can-block-on-async-code---but-you-shouldnt

Comment: https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md#avoid-using-taskresult-and-taskwait

Comment: @Charlieface ok, yes ASP.NET Core

Comment: Asynchronous requests will set aside a thread, but this thread will eventually return to the thread pool, so in theory, this is safe. For more details, please refer to [this link](https://code-maze.com/asynchronous-programming-with-async-and-await-in-asp-net-core/).